# Transition don't work on iPhone and iPad

Tags: html, ios, css

It works fine on any Browser and on all my devices but not on iPads and iPhones.
After this I deleted everything and copy the example code from [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition-property).

But there was the same problem. On the W3C site everything was fine but not on mine.

```css
.other_button {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  -ms-transition-property: width;
  -webkit-transition-property: width;
  -moz-transition-property: width;
  -o-transition-property: width;
  transition-property: width;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  background: red;
}
.other_button:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="other_button"></div>
```

Comment: Which browser do you use in your IPhone?

Comment: Try to change to: `.other_button:hover, .other_button:active {...  -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none}`

Comment: I used every Browser i could find but nothing worked. Tried the :active before and nothing changed also with -webkit-user-select:none; and -webkit-touch-callout:none;

Comment: how you can hover on a touch device ? o.O

Comment: Try also `.other_button:hover, .other_button:focus {}`

Comment: actually i tried everyone of those :/